# spring security: disable multiple sessions on the same user not working

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

`HttpSecurity` object configed like this:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login","/loginPage","/static/login.html","/","/index","/static/authenticationErr.html","/static/duplicatedUserErr.html").permitAll()
    .and()
    .httpBasic()
    .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint)
    .and()
    .addFilterAt(customAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
    .and()
    .formLogin()
    .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
    .loginPage("/loginPage")
    .permitAll()
    .and()
    .logout()
    .logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessHandler(customLogoutHandler)
    .permitAll()

    .and()
    .sessionManagement() // not working??
    .maximumSessions(1)
    .maxSessionsPreventsLogin(true)
    .expiredUrl("/static/duplicatedUserErr.html")
    ;
```

Here is what I tried: by following the spring security reference at https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions and source code trace, I found out the key to determine if this is a duplicate login session is this part of code written in method `onAuthentication` of class `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy`:

```
final List<SessionInformation> sessions = sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(
            authentication.getPrincipal(), false);
```

then base on the size of this list, compare with the maximumSessions limit deined in `HttpSecurity` config to check if this is an duplicated user. After debugging, I know every time a user try to login, this line of code will be called, however no matter how many times try to login in my browsers, `sessions` object always be null, it turns out the `principals` field defined in `SessionRegistryImpl` has been a empty map since it is created and never be filled with new elements.

Here is other detail of my config:

AuthenticationProvider: `org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider`

UserDetailService: 
CustomUserDetailsService implements `UserDetailsService`

UserDetails:
 `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`

AuthenticationProcessingFilter: 
CustomAuthenticationFilter extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`

**Updated**:

```
@Bean
public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    CustomAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter("/login");
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManagerBean());
    filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);

    filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionControlAuthenticationStrategy());
    return filter;
}
```

Can someone give me a light of this?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have figured it out, you have to create beans by following this reference  [https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions](http://%20https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#concurrent-sessions), and you have to set `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` bean manually to `CustomAuthenticationFilter` , and then in your `ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy` bean, set ExceptionIfMaximumExceeded as true so it will throw a `SessionAuthenticationException` when a duplicate seesion of the same user created.
My code of above description is like this:

```
@Bean
public CustomAuthenticationFilter customAuthenticationFilter() throws Exception {
    CustomAuthenticationFilter filter = new CustomAuthenticationFilter("/login");
    filter.setAuthenticationManager(this.authenticationManagerBean());
    filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(failureHandler);
    filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successHandler);
    //If don't set it here, spring will inject a compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy bean automatically, but looks like it didn't work as expected for me
    filter.setSessionAuthenticationStrategy(compositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy());
    return filter;
}
@Bean
    public ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy sessionControlAuthenticationStrategy() {
        ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy csas = new ConcurrentSessionControlAuthenticationStrategy(sessionRegistry());
        csas.setExceptionIfMaximumExceeded(true);
        return csas;
    }
```